# How to verify Cluster working in node js?

Tags: node.js

I am new to nodejs and currently playing with its features, one of the important feature I came across is **Cluster**, I tried to implement that for my sample application using expressjs, angular and nodejs.

Cluster code:

```
var cluster = require('cluster');

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    var cpuCount = require('os').cpus().length;
    for (var i = 0; i < cpuCount; i += 1) {
        cluster.fork();
    }
} else {
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var exportRouter=require('./routers/exportRouter');
    var process = require('process');

    fakeDB = [];
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    app.use(require('./routers/exportRouter.js'));

    console.log('process Id :',process.pid);
    app.listen(3000, function(){
        console.log('running on 30000');    
    });
}
```

I have added following code in my routers to block the event loop,so when I make first request It will block one nodejs worker. so if another user makes call while first node is blocked second worker should pick that up.

router code :

```
var express = require('express');
var exportRouter = express.Router();
var process = require('process');

exportRouter.get('/getMe',function(req,res){
    console.log('I am using process   ',process.pid);
    console.log('get is called');
    fakeDB.push(req.query.newName+' '+ process.pid);
    res.send(req.query.newName + ' ' + process.pid);
    console.log('New name received   ',fakeDB);


    console.log('New name received   ',fakeDB);
    var d = new Date().getTime();
    console.log('old ',d)

    var x = d+10000;
    console.log('should stop post ',x);
    while(true){

        var a = new Date().getTime();
        //console.log('new ',a)
         if(x<a){
            break;
         }
    }
    console.log('I am releasing event loop for ',process.pid);

});

module.exports = exportRouter;
```

it does not serve other request using another worker and waits for blocked node worker.. BTW I am using node js version 0.12.7(64bit) and 4 cpus.

THanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it does not serve other request using another worker and waits for blocked node worker

Your testing methodology is probably wrong. Here's a simplified version of your sample.

```
var cluster = require('cluster')
if (cluster.isMaster) {
  var cpuCount = require('os').cpus().length
  for (var i = 0; i < cpuCount; i += 1) {
    cluster.fork()
  }
} else {
  var express = require('express')
  var app = express()
  console.log('process Id:', process.pid)
  app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log('pid', process.pid, 'handler start, blocking CPU')
    var i = 0;
    while (i < 10e9) {
      i++

    }
    console.log('pid', process.pid, 'unblocked, responding')
    res.send('thanks')
  })
  app.listen(3003, function () {
    console.log('running on 3003')
  })
}
```

If I run this in one terminal, then open two other terminals and as quickly as possible fire off a `curl localhost:3003` in each terminal, I can see the second request arrives and begins processing before the first request gets a response:

```
pid 53434 handler start, blocking CPU
pid 53437 handler start, blocking CPU
pid 53434 unblocked, responding
pid 53437 unblocked, responding
```